# The word "doubt" as a substitute for the word "question."

Tags: nouns

I

I live in India and I have noticed that in Indian English it is normal to use the noun "doubt" as one would use the noun "question" in Western English.

Examples:

"He had many *doubts* regarding the subject, so he asked his teacher to answer those *doubts*."

"Sir, I have a *doubt*, what is the square root of 64?"

Is this usage of the noun "doubt" unique to Indian English, or is it also acceptable in Western English?

Comment: Definitely the exact same question. I even live in the same area as is being discussed in that post. I guess this question can be deleted.

Comment: The comment starts with **possible** and other users might not agree with my comment. You don't need to delete this question right now as there is a possibility some users could give you a comment or an answer.

Comment: Alright, but the question you linked to and the others linked to in that answered my doubt (sic) quite thoroughly.